# Drupal token current-page:query

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, token, drupal-panels

I need to get the value of a field that is on the "Parent page" of one of my content panes. I would like to do this through the use of tokens, and the only seemingly useful one that I can find is `current-page:query:?` I am assuming that I need to replace the '?' with something in order to get the field from the "Parent node".

How do I use this token, or is there another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a URL like

```
http://dev.druedu.com/node/add/answer?field_answer=161
```

and want the value of the `field_answer` token, do this

```
current-page:query:field_answer
```

Answer (score 2):

That's right, here another option if you are using "Clean URL" in your Drupal Metadata & Search option in your Drupal Configurations:

**Args Format:** For urls formatted like http://server/node/120/**key** use
 [current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:2] to return **key**.

More info: [https://www.drupal.org/node/296453](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)

Remember always you need install [Token Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)
If you are using Webform 3.x you need to install a patch also; with webform 4.x everything is Ok.

Answer (score -3):

I figgured it out, I can just use the contexts in panels!

Comment: Great explanation, thank you from the dev community.

Comment: @EricLavault this question is old as sin, but thanks for pointing out my poor answer anyways. I have since forgotten the correct solution, or I would update, but in lieu of that, I have moved to select the top answer as the correct one.